# JAPE grammar rule

Tags: nlp, gate

I am new to GATE, JAPE. having no idea about annotation. I go through the documents but still, I find difficulties in writing rules like what to put in input:, what is rule()xyz --> with rule name, macros ect. How to start for beginners?

LIKE:

```
Phase:firstpass       //1 what is this phase 
Input:  Lookup        //2 when to use lookup or other other things, how to know
Options: control = brill  //3 Got it
Rule: SportsCategory      //4 Got it
Priority: 20              //5 Got it
(                              //6 
{Lookup.majorType == "Sports"} //7 wht is majorType, from where it comes 
): label                        //8 what we writeafter : 
-->                             //9 
:label.Sport = {rule= "SportsCategory" }
```

Comment: try google: jape tutorial

Comment: This is a good start https://gate.ac.uk/sale/thakker-jape-tutorial/ (if not the only place)